# How to decode utf-8 text from bs4 soup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding, python-requests

I'm extracting all titles and urls from [this website](https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos) but it's comming with some symbols in place of accents, even after checking the requests encoding beeing utf-8.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos"

r = requests.get(url)
print(f"The encoding is {r.encoding}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

lista_de_discursos = soup.find_all(name="a", attrs={"class": "summary"})

for x in lista_de_discursos:
    print(x.text)
    print("---")
```

Here is the output with the encoding comming from requests and some article titles.

```
The encoding is utf-8
Discurso do Presidente da Rep�blica, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a apresenta��o do Projeto da Ponte de acesso ao Bairro Boa Esperan�a e ao Quilombo S�o Pedro - Eldorado/SP
---
Discurso do Presidente da Rep�blica, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a Apresenta��o de Projeto da Ponte sobre o Rio Pariquera-A�u - Pariquera-A�u/SP
---
Discurso do Presidente da Rep�blica, Jair Bolsonaro, durante entrega do Disc�bolo de Ouro - Pal�cio do Planalto
```

How could I get `República` and `apresentação` instead of `Rep�blica` and `apresenta��o`.

In other words, how can I set the encoding to UTF-8 at my output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This functionality is environment dependent.

  - The original code prints the characters without issue in a python console, but not in JupyterLab.
  - As noted by [Henrique Branco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12787236/henrique-branco), in VS Code, it was the difference between the `Console` or `Terminal` output.
- Change `r.text` to `r.content.decode('utf-8')`
- Alternatively, as commented by [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom), `repr(x.text)` works as well.
- The difference is, all of the contents in the `soup` object are decoded, compared to just the output `str`, when printing.

```py
url = "https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos"

r = requests.get(url)
print(f"The encoding is {r.encoding}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')

lista_de_discursos = soup.find_all(name="a", attrs={"class": "summary"})

for x in lista_de_discursos:
    print(x.text)
    print("---")

[out]:
The encoding is utf-8
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a apresentação do Projeto da Ponte de acesso ao Bairro Boa Esperança e ao Quilombo São Pedro - Eldorado/SP
---
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a Apresentação de Projeto da Ponte sobre o Rio Pariquera-Açu - Pariquera-Açu/SP
---
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante entrega do Discóbolo de Ouro - Palácio do Planalto
---
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a Homenagem póstuma ao músico Pinto do Acordeon - Brasilia/DF
---
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante o Lançamento do Programa Norte Conectado - Palácio do Planalto
---
Discurso do Presidente da República, Jair Bolsonaro, durante a  Solenidade de inauguração da Usina de Energia Fotovoltaica -  Caldas Novas/GO
```

### Environment / Packages

```
jupyterlab 2.2.6
Windows 10
beautifulsoup4 4.9.1
requests 2.24.0
python 3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It may sound weird, but the only reason why this was printing like that was because I was using the output from VS Code. Strange behavior, but problem solved.

**OUTPUT in VS Code**

[image]

**TERMINAL in VS Code**

[image]

I'll considered this question as answered, as soon as the problem was solved!

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly why I asked you to try `print(repr(x.text))`, to see if the problem was in the input or the output.  Turns out it was the output.  Obviously the Output window doesn't handle Unicode.